# Creating Array of objects and read the information

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a Box[] with box objects(i.e.boxes[box1,box2,box3]),then writing a method to access the element in Box[], I encountered no Pointer error.

```
public class GameState
{
public static final int noOfSquares = 10; // the extent of the board in both directions
public static final int noOfBoxes   = 3;  // the number of boxes in the game 

private Square[][] board; // the current state of the board 
private Box[] boxes;      // the current state of the boxes 
private int score;        // the current score

// initialise the instance variables for board 
// all squares and all boxes are initially empty 
public GameState()
{
    score = 0;
    board = new Square[10][10];       
    Box[] boxes = new Box[3];
    for(int j =0;j<boxes.length;j++){
        boxes[j] = new Box();
     }

 // return the current state of the board 
public Square[][] getBoard()
{
    return board;
}

// return the current contents of Box i 
public Box getBox(int i)
{
    if (0 <= i && i < noOfBoxes)       **// here doesn't work**
    { 
        return boxes[i];
      }
    else         {
        return null;
}
}

// return the current score
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}

  }

}
```

There are no errors in the box class,in which Box() creates a new null box. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: There's no object reference on the indicated line so its probably on the following statement...

Answer (score 2):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `boxes`. Replace

```
Box[] boxes = new Box[3];
```

with

```
boxes = new Box[3];
```